# run django web application with apache and mod_wsgi with python3 virtuaenvironment on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

This is the first time I am deploying django app on apache with mod_wsgi,using python3 virtual environment. directory like below

---

**(DJango_RestFramework) User@User-virtual-machine:~/Project/Sample$ dir 
db.sqlite3  manage.py  Sample  static**

---

Added **STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/home/User/Project/Sample/static/")** at the bottom of **settings.py** file then applied **./manage.py collectstatic**
right after then changed  **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** file like below

```
    <VirtualHost :*80>
    Alias /static /home/User/Project/Sample/static

    <Directory /home/User/Project/Sample/static>

            Require all granted

    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/User/Project/Sample/Sample>

            <Files wsgi.py>

                    Require all granted

            </Files>

    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess Sample python-path=/home/User/Project/:/home/User/Project/DJango_RestFramework/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup Sample
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/User/Project/Sample/Sample/wsgi.py
   </VirtualHost>
```

finally applied these commands

---

**1.chmod 664  /home/User/Project/Sample/db.sqlite3, 2.sudo chown :www-data  /home/User/Project/Sample/db.sqlite3, 3.sudo chown :www-data /home/User/Project/Sample, 4.sudo service apache2 restart**
got **Internal Server Error** If I checked at error.log it' was showing that [Tue Dec 12 15:02:32.095065 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 1331:tid 140188564576000] [remote 127.0.0.1:5937] ImportError: No module named 'django'.

---

don't know where I mistaken please help me.
thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure you installed django at the virtualenv?.  Specifically, at the `/home/User/Project/DJango_RestFramework/lib/python3.5/site-packages` path, is there a folder named `django`?

Comment: yes. django folder existed inside site-packages.(DJango_RestFramework) aesubuntu@aesubuntu-virtual-machine:~/Project/Sample$ django-admin --version
2.0

Comment: File system paths are case sensitive. Are you sure you meant to have capital J in ``DJango_RestFramework``. Also read up on how to configure Python virtual environments in the preferred way at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html You don't currently use the recommended way.

Comment: should I create  linkings between /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/